# Unable to receive all published messages [AWS IOT]

Tags: mqtt, publish-subscribe, aws-iot

I'm trying to publish 1000 messages per second using 5 processes with 200 messages each on a unique topic. And trying to listen using 5 processes each one listening on one topic on which messages are being published.

The problem is I'm unable to receive all the thousand messages and the number of messages received is not constant every time I follow this process.

As far as I understood AWS IOT should be allowing 3000 inbound messages per second.

Comment: I guess there could be lots of possible reasons why you aren't seeing enough messages. Maybe you aren't generating enough, maybe your network connection is limiting performance. Maybe there is a limiting factor at the broker end. You have control of some things. What have you tried changing to see if the performance changes?

Comment: I have put a print statement to ensure that I'm sending the desired number of messages and I'm running the program in an ec2 instance so I don't think network connection can be a reason. As far as I understood from the AWS docs, the number of inbound messages can be 3000, so I think I no way close to limits. And I have set QoS level to 1. I have tried sending it on multiple topics/single topic, decreasing the number of messages that are published on a topic.

Comment: I presume you have instrumented each process with to programmatically count how many messages the sender process is sending, and how many the receiver process is receiving (using, say, time.perf_counter)? Is there any way you can run both the sender and receiver locally (using localhost on two different ports as endpoints)?

Comment: Please attach publisher/subscriber code

Comment: Thanks for commenting on this issue. The problem is that i was calling publish method in a loop and my program is terminated immediately after publishing, But the publish method is creating a thread to do publish network request. So by the time my main program exists all the threads haven't published the payload due to which i was unable to get all the message. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

Try to publish data at QOS-1 or QOS-2 level.

**What is Quality of Service?**

The Quality of Service (QoS) level is an agreement between sender and receiver of a message regarding the guarantees of delivering a message. There are 3 QoS levels in MQTT:

At most once (0)

At least once (1)

Exactly once (2).

When talking about QoS there are always two different parts of delivering a message: publishing client to broker and broker to subscribing client. We need to look at them separately since there are subtle differences. The QoS level for publishing client to broker is depending on the QoS level the client sets for the particular message. When the broker transfers a message to a subscribing client it uses the QoS of the subscription made by the client earlier. That means, QoS guarantees can get downgraded for a particular receiving client if subscribed with a lower QoS.

**Why is Quality of Service important?**

QoS is a major feature of MQTT, it makes communication in unreliable networks a lot easier because the protocol handles retransmission and guarantees the delivery of the message, regardless how unreliable the underlying transport is. Also it empowers a client to choose the QoS level depending on its network reliability and application logic.